# Make all lines of tables thicker

Tags: tables

I know that solutions to a similar problem already exist, such as the `boldline` package, but the problem with such solutions is that we have to manually select which lines to make thicker, which would be time-consuming in my case.

P.S. I want a bit thicker lines because I think such tables would complement my use of the `mlmodern` package nicely (it is ugly to have bolder letters yet very thin table lines).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Second edit: if you prefer to use the classic `tabular`, `\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{5pt}` before the array seems to do the trick too.

Edit: following your comment below, here's a version that should be better. Remember that, in `tabularray`, all lines are specified as options of the environment, not inside the content of the array. So you'll specify thickness at the same time as you specify which lines are drawn.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{colspec={ccc}, hline{1,3}={3pt}, vline{1}={1pt}}
1 & 2 & 3\\
4 & 5 & 6    
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result2]

Original answer: `tabularray` seems to do what you want:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{colspec={ccc}, hlines={3pt}, vlines={1pt}}
1 & 2 & 3\\
4 & 5 & 6    
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

It's two options and not one, but it's still efficient I think.

Comment: The problem with this is that now all the lines of the table are showing, including the ones I didn't explicitly insert.

Comment: @Godbless I edited my answer, I hope it's better now.

Comment: Thanks, this works now. It would be handy, however, to have a simple macro which sets the thickness of all already visible lines of tables in a document.

Comment: I skimmed `tabularray`'s documentation to see if there was some sort of default value for this, but didn't find anything, sorry.

Comment: I added a second solution that seems to work and doesn't use `tabularray`.